# How can I make a textBox value equal to a datagrivew cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, datagridview, textbox

I have a winform and 6 textboxes, when I press button1 each textboxes get populated with their corresponding datagridview cell values. When I press button2 after entering a value in textbox6 how can I make a label show the matching value of any of the 5 textboxes. My code below doesn't work. Thank you.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Equals(textBox2.Text))
        {
            label1.Text = "this is equal to textBox1";


        }
```

Comment: What do you mean your code doesn't work? It looks okay to me.

Comment: Their are 5 textboxes and 5 if's, it becomes true only for the last if's.

Comment: In other words label1 says not equal to for textbox1 thru textbox4 and equal to for the last one. If I delete textbox5 than textbox4 only becomes true and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all textboxes but #6 and compare the text of your textBox6:

```
foreach (TextBox control in Controls) //all textboxes but textbox6, because you dont want to compare it with itself
            {
                if (control.Text.Equals(textBox6.Text) && textBox6 != control)
                {
                    label1.Text = control.Text;
                }
            }
```

If you have more textboxes in your form you need to exclude them as well to prevent the loop from comparing them too. You can achive this by putting them in a panel of something similar.